# How to make 3D pie chart in pentaho CDE?And where is the location of xml to edit its properties?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to make 3Dpie chart in Pentaho.

In several forums they said that what we want is to add is-3D parameter to `XML`. But I don't know where `chartData.xml` is.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make 3D pie chart. [CCC](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ccc/) (Community Chart Components charting library which is used by Pentaho CDE) does not support 3D chart effects.

Check an answer at the bottom of this [Pentaho forum archive](http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-151676.html) from the CCC developer.